# URL REWRITE is navigating to /directory_name/<param> instead of /file/<param>

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've recently started dabbling in MOD_REWRITE to make cleaner URLs for my websites. Most of my URLS work except for when I try to add the file name before the parameter within the URL.

For example:

I am trying to make my URL read http://www.kickstartforex.com/strategy/name-of-strategy and the URL should rewrite to http://www.kickstartforex.com/strategy.php?name=name-of-strategy.

Therefore, the RewriteRule that I've written for this particular instance reads as such:

```
RewriteRule ^strategy/([a-z]+)$ /strategy.php?name=$1 [L]
```

However, when I navigate to my desirable URL, I am receiving a 404 error insisting that this page does not exist.

My suspicions lead me to believe that in navigating to the URL listed above, my website is trying to access /strategy/ as a directory which does not exist and therefore throws the 404.

I am obviously having the same issue with /lessons/parameter as well as /tutorial/parameter but if I can resolve one instance of this, I am sure the other will follow suit.

How would I be able to list "/strategy/parameter" to access /strategy.php without the server trying to access the directory "/strategy/"?

My .htaccess code is listed below.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force search engines to use kickstartforex.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^kickstartforex\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://kickstartforex.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^about$ /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^strategy/([a-z]+)$ /strategy.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lesson/([a-z]+)$ /lesson.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tutorial/([a-z]+)$ /tutorial.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance! (:

Comment: Are you sure your rewrite rules or the htaccess file are being read? If you add a bunch of gibberish in the htaccess file, does it give you a 500 error?

Comment: The rewrite rules are definitely being read. If I navigate to http://www.kickstartforex.com/contact or /about, everything works as expected.